# why the battery temperature could be so low?

Tags: android, battery

I can't understand why some phone battery temperature could be **Negative Value**!

Winter is coming?

I find the temperature value may be **-200, -400 or -150** and these are too low!

This is my code:

```
            Intent intent = mContext.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(
                    "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"));
            if (intent != null) {
                level = intent.getIntExtra("temperature", -1);
            }
```

I didn't find answer in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html  .

Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean that it is sometimes a negative value, or that it is always so?

Comment: @TaylorKidd it is always so...

Comment: What kind of phone is it? Is it not because the phone doesn't have a battery sensor, so just a random negative value is returned?